# my h2 is sitting on top of h1, how to get it below h1?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

so here is the situation, i actually want **h2** to be **below h1** but its ***sitting on top of it***.. and i don't want it to be added in same header section, i want it to have seperate section like i created "*content-section*" i know that `position:absolute;` is causing the problem how to solve this.. if i disturb positon property it will effect my **Nav-section** so what to do now? need help

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}


/* HEADER SECTION*/

.header-section {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: absolute;
}


/* HEADING */

h1 {
  display: inline;
}


/* Nav-section */

.nav-section {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  left: 80%;
}

.nav-section li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}


/* BACKGROUND IMG */

body {
  background: url("coffee.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}


/* CONTENT - SECTION */

.Content-section {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>journey</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header-section">
    <h1>
      journey
    </h1>
    <ul class="nav-section">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Home</li>
    </ul>
  </header>

  <header class="Content-section">
    <h2>
      Welcome to my world<br> where it all Began...
    </h2>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: well, if you ended with something like this means that  you made it wrong, so instead of fixing a bad thing, i think it's better to re-think about a better way ... there is absolutely no need to make all your content position:absolute

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding-top` property to your `.Content-section` . Like this

```
.Content-section {
  padding-top: 80px;
}
```

You can change the `padding-bottom` as `exact height of your` `.header-section`.

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}


/* HEADER SECTION*/

.header-section {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: absolute;
}


/* HEADING */

h1 {
  display: inline;
}


/* Nav-section */

.nav-section {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  left: 80%;
}

.nav-section li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}


/* BACKGROUND IMG */

body {
  background: url("coffee.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}


/* CONTENT - SECTION */

.Content-section {
  padding-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>journey</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header-section">
    <h1>
      journey
    </h1>
    <ul class="nav-section">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Home</li>
    </ul>
  </header>

  <header class="Content-section">
    <h2>
      Welcome to my world<br> where it all Began...
    </h2>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: :) again some mistake in your answer. `Add padding-bottom property to your .Content-section`. is that correct??

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a **"Filler"** that will act as the `position:absolute`'s block container. This is not responsive, because you will need to use a fixed height value.

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}


/* HEADER SECTION*/

.header-section {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  /*need a fixed height*/
}

#filler {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}


/* HEADING */

h1 {
  display: inline;
}


/* Nav-section */

.nav-section {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  left: 80%;
}

.nav-section li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}


/* BACKGROUND IMG */

body {
  background: url("coffee.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}


/* CONTENT - SECTION */

.Content-section {}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="header-section">
    <h1>
      journey
    </h1>
    <ul class="nav-section">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Home</li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <div id="filler"></div>
  <header class="Content-section">
    <h2>
      Welcome to my world<br> where it all Began...
    </h2>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a `padding-top` to your `.Content-section`

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}


/* HEADER SECTION*/

.header-section {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: absolute;
}


/* HEADING */

h1 {
  display: inline;
}


/* Nav-section */

.nav-section {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  left: 80%;
}

.nav-section li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
}


/* BACKGROUND IMG */

body {
  background: url("coffee.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}


/* CONTENT - SECTION */

.Content-section {
padding-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>journey</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header-section">
    <h1>
      journey
    </h1>
    <ul class="nav-section">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Home</li>
    </ul>
  </header>

  <header class="Content-section">
    <h2>
      Welcome to my world<br> where it all Began...
    </h2>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```